# Dynamic direction of ORDER in ActiveRecord query when using a JOIN

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm attempting to cleanup some code that was flagged as being vulnerable to SQL injection. As such, I am converting a lot of raw SQL query strings over to ActiveRecord's methods. One type of query that I'm having an issue finding an equivalent for is when I want to apply ordering (`order`) to  a nested attribute.

If I have an `Account` and `User` object and I wanted to order the result by the `user_id`, I *could* do this (this is what the code currently has):

```
->(direction) { Account.joins(:users).order("users.id #{direction}").first }
```

However, this is vulnerable to SQL injection.

I know that if I'm ordering by attributes of `Account`, you can just pass a hash to `order`

```
->(direction) { Account.joins(:users).order(created_at: direction).first }
```

However, using a string as the attribute to sort by (since it's nested) doesn't result in the correct query:

```
->(direction) { Account.joins(:users).order('users.id': direction).first }
# SELECT  `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`account_id` = `accounts`.`id`  ORDER BY `accounts`.`users.id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

And using a nested hash also doesn't work

```
->(direction) { Account.joins(:users).order(users: {id: direction}).first }
```

I know that I can enforce `direction` to be one of the accepted values with some additional logic, but was wondering if there was an easy way to do this via ActiveRecord's querying that I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering by a joined association is only supported via strings I fear.

However, it is possible to [merge](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge)  scopes which allows you to write:

```
->(direction) { Account.joins(:users).merge(User.order(id: direction})).first }
```

This does prevent values other than `[:asc, :desc, :ASC, :DESC, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"]` for direction (plucked from the ArgumentError message). In my opinion it comes at the cost of decreased readability but one can try to mitigate the problem and increase reusability at the same time by defining the order as a named scope in the `User` class.

```
class User
   ...
   self.ordered_by_id(direction)
     order(id: direction})
   end
   ...
end
```

Which enables you to use

```
->(direction) { 
  Account.joins(:users).merge(User.ordered_by_id(direction)).first
}
```

Granted, in the current example this does not shine yet, but using `merge` with more complicated scopes can greatly reduce duplication.

Comment: Can you paste an example of what is not working as I fear that I didn't quite catch the problem, yet?

Comment: Sorry about that, was loading the wrong version of the file. It works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think `order` isn't as advanced as it could be.

But as you expect `asc` or `desc` only you could filter it:

```
direction = (%w[asc desc] & [direction.downcase])[0] || 'asc'
Account.joins(:users).order("users.id #{direction}").first
```